# Disk full error despite free space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

On my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, I have about 150GB of disk space but my `/` directory is nearly full with about 15GB of space used.

Here is the output of `df` command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       147G   14G  126G  10% /
/dev/sda2       240M  7.8M  232M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       782G   64G  718G   9% /media/mirhosseini/ADATA HD710
```

And the output of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev              478466    604    477862    1% /dev
tmpfs             485498   1049    484449    1% /run
/dev/sda3        9822208 351043   9471165    4% /
tmpfs             485498     79    485419    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             485498      6    485492    1% /run/lock
tmpfs             485498     18    485480    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         24339  24339         0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop0         10765  10765         0  100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2         10764  10764         0  100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop4         62342  62342         0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop3         24339  24339         0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop5         15827  15827         0  100% /snap/snap-store/433
/dev/loop6         15827  15827         0  100% /snap/snap-store/454
/dev/loop7           459    459         0  100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop8           462    462         0  100% /snap/snapd/7777
/dev/sda2              0      0         0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs             485498    102    485396    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1      752931592  14911 752916681    1% /media/mirhosseini/ADATA HD710
```

As you can see there is about 126GB of free space, but I faced the "unsufficient space" or "disk full" error.

This is the screenshot from disk usage analyzer:

[image: screenshot of disk usage analyzer]

Comment: What was the application that reported insufficient space / disk full?

Comment: @Owl phpStorm was the first application that showed the error.

Comment: Can you reliably duplicate the problem? If so,please tell us the steps.

Comment: @user535733 sorry I don`t understand what you mean by "duplicate the problem"

Comment: If we were sitting at your machine, what steps would we need to follow in order to get the disk full error?

Comment: @user535733 actually I did not face the error from yesterday but first time when phpstrom was indexing the project files show the error and after that I face the error when I was extracting an archive.As you see the properties of my partitions did you find any mistake?